# How do you best select values from a 2d numpy array using a list of coordinates?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to understand the best way to pull values from a 2d NumPy array using a list of coordinates (without using loops).

For example:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([
    ['AA','AB','AC'],
    ['BA','BB','BC'],
    ['CA','CB','CC']
])

coordinates = [(0,0), (1,1)]
```

After some experimenting:

```
# This works but does not return what I expected
# I expected ['AA','BB'], but returned ['AB,'AB']
arr[(0,0), (1,1)]

# This does not work
arr[*coordinates]
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use double indexing. The first array is the assigned to `x` coordinates and another to `y` cordinates as follows:

```
x, y = np.transpose(np.array(coordinates))
arr[x, y]
```

Try to avoid list comprehensions while using `numpy` :)

Answer (score 0):

I mean you can always do

```
[arr[coordinates[0]],arr[coordinates[1]]]
```

to get the result you wanted. This will evaluate to ['AA','BB'].

Generalizing a bit for any size list of coordinates you can do :

```
result = [arr[coordinate] for coordinate in coordinates ]
```

Is this what you're going for?

Answer (score 0):

**Using list comprehension:**

```
result = [arr[c] for c in coordinates]
```

**Code sample:**

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([["AA", "AB", "AC"], ["BA", "BB", "BC"], ["CA", "CB", "CC"]])

coordinates = [(0, 0), (1, 1)]
result = [arr[c] for c in coordinates]
print(result)
```

**Outputs:**

```
['AA', 'BB']
```